# Using a function return for parameters of other function (in python)

Tags: function, parameters, python-3.x

So, I was wondering if it was possible to use the return information from one function as the parameters for another without using a variable. The function I am trying to use takes two parameters (and self because it's part of a class) and the other function returns two values. The best I can get is:

```
import ccrlib
authinfo = ccrlib.getauth()
session = ccrlib.CCRSession(authinfo[0], authinfo[1])
```

Otherwise I would have to run getauth twice:

```
import ccrlib
session = ccrlib.CCRSession(ccrlib.getauth()[0], ccrlib.getauth()[1])
```

Which is most obviously less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use star unpacking:

```
session = ccrlib.CCRSession(*ccrlib.getauth())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just figured it out a few seconds ago :/ Why is it that I never get the hard questions answered? *facepalm*